# Reading a part of file in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

**Goal:** To read a part/particular section of file using NodeJS.

**My code:**

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('/test/index.html', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
 console.log(data);
});
```

**Problem:** This is reading whole file. And i want to read the text between *body* tag of html file.

**Output in console:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Card</h2>
  <div class="card">
     <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
     <div class="container">
        <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4> 
        <p>Engineer</p> 
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parse the text, and extract the desired part.

using Regex its possible but [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1271037).
for parse html its recommended use [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) (see example), in your case (select by node) you can also use "simple" xml reader as [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js).

using cheerio :

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('/test/index.html', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
   if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
   }
   const $ = cheerio.load(data);
   console.log($('body'));
});
```

Comment: `$('body').html()`, I believe.